# Visio 2013 Looking for a way to have a title for each page

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

I can reference the Page.Name but I would also like to have a more specific and longer title than what I use in the Page.Name field.

For Example Page.Name = DWG-0001 and Page.Title = "Boiler #2 Air Controllers"

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

I have a title block in the background that referneces the Page.Name. But I cant find away to add a custom title for each page but put the reference in a text field on the background.

I added a Data Property to the background page and referenced it, but of course all pages using the background have the same data in that custom property.

I guess I would like to add the custom property to the foreground page (automatically every time one is created), but put my reference to it on the background.

Thanks